# What does TabbedRenderer in xamarin do?

Tags: android, xamarin

I understand that tabbedpage renderers are used for us to render tabbed pages(Display tabbed pages) but what are TabbedRenders and what are they used for?

I have tried searching and I think that it has something to do with the design of the tabs on a tabpage such as their background color.

Does that mean that if we use a custom renderer to modify TabbedRenderer we can change the shape of each of these tabs?

With regards to modifying the shape of each of these tabs using xamarin for android is there any advice as to what functions should I look into? (Since I am new to android and xamarin )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what are TabbedRenders and what are they used for?

It's important to understand why XF uses renderers, as we know, XF is kind of UI toolkit, when you use `TabbedPage` control of XF, for android platform it actually use its [TabbedPageRenderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/TabbedPageRenderer.cs) to render as a [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html). For other platforms, it is renderered to their native controls too, you can check them by reading the source code of [Xamarin Forms](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms).

> Does that mean that if we use a custom renderer to modify TabbedRenderer we can change the shape of each of these tabs?

So for this question, the answer is: It's up to the native control of each platform. For `TabbedPage` of android platform, I think it's possible. You will need to customize it by creating your custom renderer and inherit from the `TabbedPageRenderer`. There are [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) about what is `custom renderer` how to use `custom renderer`, you may take a look.

Quote from the official document:

> Xamarin.Forms user interfaces are rendered using the native controls of the target platform, allowing Xamarin.Forms applications to retain the appropriate look and feel for each platform. Custom Renderers let developers override this process to customize the appearance and behavior of Xamarin.Forms controls on each platform.

Your last question:

> With regards to modifying the shape of each of these tabs using xamarin for android is there any advice as to what functions should I look into? (Since I am new to android and xamarin )

It's not about any functions, as I said, we need to create our own custom renderer which inherits from the `TabbedPageRenderer` for android platform and override some properties to achieve what we want.

You can refer to my answers in the following questions:

1. [Xamarin forms Android how We change Tabbed Page Icon Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450085/xamarin-forms-android-how-we-change-tabbed-page-icon-size/44493711#44493711)
2. [How can I place a button in the the tabs of a TabbedPage in Xamarin.Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44507091/how-can-i-place-a-button-in-the-the-tabs-of-a-tabbedpage-in-xamarin-forms/44511454#44511454)